# How to run xmlstarlet commands on Heroku

Tags: java, shell, spring-boot, heroku

I have build.xml where a shell script fires `xmlstarlet ed -L -s "/Package/types[name='$TYPENAME']" -t elem -n members -v "$ENTITY" $SCRIPTFILE` command to create xml nodes.

```
    if [[ "$2" != *"destructive"* ]]
    then
            xmlstarlet ed -L -s /Package -t elem -n version -v "43.0" $SCRIPTFILE
    fi
    xmlstarlet ed -L -i /Package -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" $SCRIPTFILE
```

This works fine when running locally via `springboot` app as I have xmlstartlet installed. But when I host this in Heroku it fails with `generate_package_unix6199938543217323388.sh: line 193: xmlstarlet: command not found`. Is there a workaround or a way to install xmlstartlet on heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the xmlstarlet apt package by using the [apt buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). To do so, create an `Aptfile` in the root directory of your app with the following contents:

```
xmlstarlet
```

Make sure you add it to Git with `git add` and `git commit`.

Then add the apt buildpack to your app by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku-community/apt
```

When you redeploy, the xmlstarlet command should be installed.

Comment: When you say `aptfile`, the file name should be aptfile or file extension should be `anyfilename.apt`

Comment: Ok, this works, created a file named as `Aptfile` and added `xmlstarlet` and all works fine now.